# Bound of certain integral and approximation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given that $0<x<a$, prove that the following inequality holds:

$$\frac{2x}{a}< \int_{a-x}^{a+x}\frac{1}{t}dt<x (\frac{1}{a+x}+\frac{1}{a-x})$$.

Hence, or otherwise, prove that $0.68< \log 2 < 0.71$.

I can only show a weaker inequality:

$$\int_{a-x}^{a+x}\frac{1}{t}dt> \int_{a-x}^{a+x}\frac{1}{a+x}dt=\frac{2x}{a+x}$$.

Also, for the approximation of $\log 2$, I put $a+x=2, a-x=1$, so that the integral equals $\log 2$, but then the bound becomes 0.66667 and 0.75 instead of 0.68 and 0.71, please helps